# Наречие или существительное с предлогом?

Tags: словосочетания, части-речи

***"В расчет"*** - это словосочетание бывает наречием или только существительным с предлогом?

Answer (score 2):

Форма ***в расчет*** не может быть наречием, написание всегда раздельное.

Но может входить в **устойчивое** сочетание ***принимать в расчет*** со значением *учитывать, иметь в виду*.

Также возможны **свободные** словосочетания, например: *внести исправления **в расчет** по страховым взносам.*

В обоих случаях это существительное с предлогом, но в свободных сочетаниях оно обозначает конкретный предмет.

Comment: Здесь начальник Грамоты принимает вопросы. Не пробовали у него спрашивать? https://thequestion.ru/interview/33168/vladimir-pakhomov